# Read different filename using for loop

Tags: python, loops, filenames

I have some pickle datasets i would like to read, whose last digit it taking specific values for example:

```
dat1
dat3
dat6
dat9
```

I create a dataset list

```
datasets=[1,3,6,9]
```

then want to run a for loop in which i want to load the first dataset run a script then load the second etc.

i tried something like this

```
for ds in enumerate(datasets):
    X = pd.read_pickle("dat"+ds[1])
```

and obviously failed. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: That's a really convoluted way of saying `for ds in datasets: X = pd.read_pickle("dat"+ds)` (of course, you still need to convert that to `str(ds)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can't use concatenation between string and integer.
Instead, you can use a f-string like `f"dat{ds[1]}"` or just cast the ds part into a str with the str function `"dat" + str(ds[1])`